# How to set and show title to pie chart using MS chart

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, mschart

I am trying to show the title at the top of the pie chart.

```
chartArea1.AxisX.Title = "Product1";                 
chartArea1.AxisX.TitleFont = new Font("Arial Bold", 15, FontStyle.Bold);    
chartArea1.AxisX.TitleAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
```

I tried by adding title to the Title collection of chart and then assigned to the chart area title. But it is not working.

What else I can do to show title at the top of pie chart?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
Chart1.Titles.Clear()
Dim newTitle As New Title("Title Here", Docking.Top, New Font("Verdana", 12), Color.Black)
Chart1.Titles.Add(newTitle)
```

**Edited:**

In order to apply different titles to different chart areas, you need to set the Title's `DockedToChartArea` property. For example, if I have a chart with 2 ChartAreas, the titles can be added like so:

```
    Title Area1Title = new Title("Title1", Docking.Top, new Font("Verdana", 12), Color.Black);
    Title Area2Title = new Title("Title2", Docking.Top, new Font("Verdana", 12), Color.Black);
    Area1Title.DockedToChartArea = Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Name;
    Area2Title.DockedToChartArea = Chart1.ChartAreas[1].Name;
    Chart1.Titles.Add(Area1Title);
    Chart1.Titles.Add(Area2Title);
```

Comment: Thank you. Now i got the titles on the top. One more thing, i have two pie chart(Chartarea) in my chart. I want to assign the title to the chartarea respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You should try `Titles.Add` method with yourChart object rather than chartArea like following

```
yourChart.Titles.Clear();   // Unnecessary if you have already clear
Title yourTitle = new Title("Title", Docking.Top, new Font("Verdana", 12), Color.Black);
yourChart.Titles.Add(yourTitle);
```

Comment: Thanks for translating my VB code. Next time leave a comment and I can do a quick edit. Copy/Pasting my answer as your own seems rude.

Comment: @ChrisZeh Ok. That's better. If I was you, would not have minded it. But I apologize as you did. I could not vote you up because question was tagged with c#, so it was just like little lesson for future :) Still I am sorry because you mind it. Please translate now and I will remove my answer and upvote you :)

Comment: No problem Sami, your answer is superior, and a lesson for me that I should be as clear and correct as possible. Next time you might consider adding to your answer something like: "Extending what Chris said...", would help against the hard feelings :-)

Comment: Well said bro. I usually don't miss to refer in such cases, you may check my answers :) and I will avoid to do ever in future. Thanks for the nice attitude.

Answer (score 1):

This is other way to add Title in fully customized manner.

```
Title testTitle = new Title();
testTitle.text = "Total";
testTitle.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 14F, FontStyle.Bold);
testTitle.IsDockedInsideChartArea = true;
testTitle.Docking = Docking.Left;
testTitle.TextOrientation = TextOrientation.Rotated270;
testTitle.DockedToChartArea = TrunkChart.ChartAreas[0].Name;
TestChart.Title.Add(testTitle);
```

Cheers